# Derivations of a formally smooth artinian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

All rings are assumed to be commutative.

Let $A$ be a ring, and $B$ an $A$-algebra which is Artinian local with the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$.

Suppose $B$ is formally smooth over $A$.

My question is whether the following is true or not:

> For any $D \in Der_A(B)$, and for any $x\in \mathfrak m$, $Dx\in \mathfrak m$.

<s>Or, saying the same thing,</s>

> $Hom_B(\Omega _{B/A},B/\mathfrak m)=0$.

I think this is true when $A$ is a field. Thanks.

**Edit:** Since $\Omega_{B/A}$ is a free $B$-mod (formal smoothness implies projectivity; it implies freeness), the above condition is equivalent to $\Omega_{B/A}=0$. Thus B: formally étale?

**Edit:** The above condition is equivalent to

$Coker(Der_A(B/\mathfrak m)\longrightarrow Der_A(B,B/\mathfrak m))=0$.

**Edit:** It is equivalent to saying that the canonical map $\Omega_{B/A}\otimes_B K\longrightarrow\Omega_{K/A}$, where $K=B/\mathfrak m$, is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have self-solved!

Localizing $A$ at the pullback of $\mathfrak{m}$, we may assume that $A\longrightarrow B$ is a local homomorphism ($B$ still remains formally smooth over $A$).

Let $\kappa$ denote the residue field of $A$, $\mathfrak{n}$ the maximal ideal of $A$.

Then by base-change
$$B\otimes_A \kappa = B/\mathfrak{n}B$$
is formally smooth over a field $\kappa$.

Since $B$ is Artinian, a fortiori Noetherian, it follows that $B/\mathfrak{n}B$ is a regular local ring, in particular, a domain.

Therefore $\mathfrak{n}B$ is a prime ideal, and hence $\mathfrak{n}B = \mathfrak{m}$.

Thus
$$D(\mathfrak{m}) = D(\mathfrak{n}B) \subset \mathfrak{n} D(B) \subset \mathfrak{n}B = \mathfrak{m}.$$